# tool to compare .h files

Tags: c, windows, ubuntu-18.04, c-header

I was wondering if there is a tool to compare C header files to the main version of those same files locally. To be more specific I have to compare the macros of the header files from the main version to the macros of the header files generated by a library. Also make sure which macros don't match or don't exist in the generated h. files. Both versions of these header files are in a local workspace. Also, the ubuntu version (ubuntu 18.04) I'm working with doesn't have a GUI so I would have to display the results on the command line.

I can also try to work it out in win10 if necessary. I appreciate any suggestions, thanks.

Comment: What tool or procedure are you using to generate the `.h` files?

Comment: it's a proprietary tool that I don't have access to. I just have access to the output .h files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, the tool you are looking for is called `diff`.  It's available on the command line with linux since the beginning of time:

```
diff {my.h} {orig.h}
```

and there are many different formats available like "side-by-side" or "unified".

If you prefer a graphical utility there are many available for linux or windows.  Just google for "diff gui" and you can find a few.

Comment: `vimdiff` is also easy to use and probably already installed on a Unix like system:)

Comment: so I found these two commands :set diffopt+=context:0 and TOhtml. I guess it would be possible to just output the different lines and saved them in an HTML file? does that sound correct?